# PHP fatal error, Composer can not import the necessary files

Tags: php, composer-php

I have some shell scripts written in PHP. I'm on a Ubuntu server in AWS where I just installed PHP 5.5 cli.

The top of my Github repo looks like this:

```
   .git
   .gitignore
   README.md
   RetailerPosData
   RetailerSiteData
   yahoo
```

I created a new user:

```
  adduser ibyte
```

and then became that user:

```
  su ibyte
  cd
```

The last cd puts me in:

```
  /home/ibyte/
```

Then I ran "git clone" to get the repo, which is also called ibyte, then I cd into it, so now I am at:

```
  /home/ibyte/ibyte/
```

This repo has 3 unrelated projects, each a set of shell scripts. I drill further down:

```
  cd RetailerSiteData
```

so I am now at:

```
  /home/ibyte/ibyte/RetailerSiteData
```

I decided I want to start using RabbitMQ so I set it up following these instructions:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html

So I create a file called "composer.json" and its entire contents are:

```
  {
    "require": {
        "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "2.5.*"
    }
  }
```

Then I run:

```
  composer install
```

which creates a "vendor" directory and installs the library.

Now I want to run this script:

```
  php -f /home/ibyte/ibyte/RetailerSiteData/load_all_data.php
```

which starts with:

```
  require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
  use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
  $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
```

and I get:

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AMQPMessage' not found
```

but I can't figure out why the path is wrong.

How can I debug this? How do I find the path that it wants?

Comment: it seems to be the case that AMQPStreamConnection was found. So it works in general. Maybe somewere a use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage; is missing in any other included script.

Comment: The error message should contain some more information about the location of the error. It would be a good idea to look at that particular file in the line given and see what it does there.